# need help cleaning data in $_POST array

Tags: php

this doesn't work.  When I enter html into the form.  For instance when I enter a horizontal rule it displays in the echo output even though the $value was passed through strip_tags.

```
function sanitizeString($var){
   $var = strip_tags($var);
   $var = htmlentities($var);
   return stripslashes($var);
}

foreach($_POST as $key => $value){
   echo $key."<br>";
   sanitizeString($value);
   echo $value."<br>";
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You aren't actually changing `$value`. You are throwing away the return value. Try `$value = sanitizeString($value);`.

Comment: or the shorthand `echo sanitizeString($value);`

Comment: That did it. I can't believe how fast responses come on this forum.  I tried to accept your answer but a orange box came telling me I have to wait 9 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
$_POST = array_map(function ($var) {
    return stripslashes(htmlentities(strip_tags($var)));
}, $_POST);


foreach ( $_POST as $key => $value ) {
    echo "$key = $value <br>";
}
```

Or Better Sill use `filter_var`

```
$_POST = array_map(function ($var) {
    return filter_var($var, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING, FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_HIGH | FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_LOW);
}, $_POST);
```

Difference

```
$var = "index.php?name=guest<script>alert('attacked')</script>";
var_dump(stripslashes(htmlentities(strip_tags($var))));
var_dump(filter_var($var, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING, FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_HIGH | FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_LOW));
```

Output

```
string 'index.php?name=guestalert('attacked')' (length=37)
string 'index.php?name=guestalert(&#39;attacked&#39;)' (length=45)
```